# How can I use File API ando/or BLOB to upload a file using a regular HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, blob, fileapi

I have a strange situation, I need to run a custom criptography on a file in the moment that the user choose the file to be uploaded.
To achieve that I am running an Applet to crypt the file at the onSubmit event, but once I get the the crypted string from the Applet how can I send that as a regular file upload?
Is there a way to create a blob and then attach it to the file input?
I dont'have access to change the application source code, everything that I can do is write a custom Javascript.
Any help would be appreciated! Thx!